# Advanced banded Lookup (Multiple criteria with arrays)

Tags: excel, indexing

I'm trying to find a formula that will be able to lookup a value from a matrix based on three known values. Colour, Size and Weight.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAtcz.png)

The first is a nominal value and the other two are continuous:

I need to be able to enter the information given in the examples to return the cost. Columns B & C need to return to be the next "greater than" value compared to the criteria.

I've managed to make this work for the first steps (using Colour + Size to find Cost) like so:

```
{=INDEX(ExampleT[Cost],MATCH(Size,IF(ExampleT[Colour] = Colour, ExampleT[Size],1)))}
```

But I can't get anything satisfactory when trying to add the extra criteria of Weight.

Does anyone have a solution? I've been searching for a long while and though there's a lot of similar questions this appears unique. Thanks in advance!

P.S. This is my first post so I'd welcome any feedback if this request isn't clear.

Comment: How did you try to combine the two?  You can do a [multiple variable Index/Match](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214142/how-to-use-the-index-and-match-worksheet-functions-with-multiple-criteria-in-excel) (see Method 2).

Comment: Hi batman, I've tried this but it works for exact matches only, if I change the match type it breaks. I've also used IF  and MIN to try to whittle it down but no luck.